# How do I troubleshoot a Baofeng UV-5R that won't receive?

Tags: baofeng, ht, equipment-troubleshooting, uv-5r, chirp

I have a couple of Baofeng UV-5R radios. I have a profile in Chirp that works great on one of them, and I foolishly pushed that profile straight over to a UV-5R without checking firmware versions. Chirp crashed, and now the radio won't receive.  I've tried resetting it to factory settings, downloading the factory settings in chirp, and then importing a csv of my channel configs, but it still doesn't make noise when I transmit.

I have noticed that it *does* receive when I hold the MONI button, but there's no indication of reception if I don't hold that button down.  It appears to behave like the squelch setting is too high, but it's currently set to 3.

For what it's worth, the radio still transmits just fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did a bit more reading, and it seems that the new version of the firmware meant I needed to use a different chirp profile.  The solution that worked for me was to find a factory image from a radio with the firmware version I have (which Chirp reported), then import my channels via csv, and clone that resulting image onto the radio.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working again. Probably best that you did re-clone the settings image correctly. For others finding this question, one other things that come to mind offhand pertaining to squelch not opening on its own might be receive tones e.g. R-DCS.

Comment: Nice work.  When I'm using CHIRP, I pretty much always start by downloading from the radio.  I keep a separate folder of CSV files with various channels and add those to the imported template.

Comment: I agree with Rafael.  Always best to begin with a download to make sure the stored data format matches the radio.

Answer (score -1):

My radio stopped receiving anything at all one day. It turned out the rubber duck antenna had broken some how.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that the original question says he can transmit normally.  If his issue was a broken antenna, then the transmitting would also be affected like reception is affected.

Answer (score -1):

You may have set the CHIRP data for a repeater as TSQL instead of tone.  Changing that might fix your problem.

Comment: This does not explain why it works on one radio but not the other.  If this were the problem, it would not work on either radio.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!